# Filezilla regex filter to exclude images

Tags: regex, filezilla

I have a trouble with a regex to filezilla filter, which exclude all .jpg .png .gif .bmp files, but anything else must stay (php, sql, html, js etc). Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

The [FileZilla docs](https://wiki.filezilla-project.org/Regular_Expressions) say:

> The flavor of regular expressions used are POSIX extended regular expressions.
>
> Note that by selecting "None of the following" as a file filter criteria type, you can effectively select those files that do match the specified criteria.

Unfortunately, POSIX regexes are very limited, so we have to do something ugly.

Use the following regex and check the *None of the following* criteria:

```
\.([jJ][pP][eE]?[gG]|[pP][nN][gG]|[bB][mM][pP])$
```